# vim python syntax not working (Partly)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

Vim only seems to highlight comments, numbers, and imported modules. So function calls, attributes, etc are all non-highlighted. I have 'syntax on' and 'filetype plugin indent on' in my vimrc. syntax highlighting works with every other language EXCEPT python. I cant figure out why it doesnt like python. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I am using vim on mac terminal (vim Version: 8.1) installed via homebrew. I have verified that this is the version I am using.

EDIT: 
output of FT: Filetype=Python 
Upon further research, it seems like perhaps my syntax highlighting is working, just not quit as good as I would of hoped. I thought I would be able to get similar syntax highlighting to something like atom

Comment: What's the output of the command `:set ft?`. Also a screenshot might be good to get an idea.

Comment: This sounds like how it's supposed to look, as the Python syntax file doesn't highlight function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended the standard Python syntax file to cover your mentioned use cases:

- Function calls
- Attributes

As well as

- variables (as distinct from object instances)
- doctests
- `self`
- string formatting
- et cetera

You can find it [here](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/vim/syntax/python.vim), and use it as a drop-in replacement for the installed `.../syntax/python.vim`. You may also wish to extend the colour file you use to take advantage of the new syntax elements, as I have done [here](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/vim/colors/jalanb.vim#L34) (but you may not like the actual colours there, many of my colleagues think them very garish).

However: do notice that it is based on the syntax file from Vim **6.1**, so is missing some more modern aspects of the language (e.g. fstrings). (Contributions are very welcome.)

It also [uses some features](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/vim/syntax/python.vim#L405) from Kien's [Rainbow Parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim), but they can be easily removed if you don't wish to use that.

Also in that directory is a [syntax file](https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/vim/syntax/doctest.vim) to cover doctest files, i.e. doctests which are written to a separate test file, not merely added to docstrings within the main source file.

Comment: Thank you so much, your color scheme looks great! I've replaced my syntax file with yours, but it doesnt seem to have picked up on the extended syntax. I'll have to fiddle around some. Do you know if I'll have to change my vim version?

Comment: Don't think a Vim version change is needed. It has worked for me all the way since version 5 (I'm now on version 8)